# Linker error when using standard library in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, g++

I have been struggling with this compilation problem for hours and I haven't been able to find any solution:

I am working on a medium size application written in "C with classes" style and using cmake. I am trying to add a `std::multimap` to a part which I am extending. I have included `<map>` and `<utility>` in the corresponding header file, and this code is my minimal example:

```
std::pair<int,int> y(5,10);
cout << y.first << ", " << y.second << endl;

std::map<int,int> x;
//x.insert(y);
//x[2] = 4;
cout << x.empty() << endl;
```

This works as expected unless I enable either of the commented lines, in which case I get the following error from the linker:

```
In function `std::_Rb_tree<int, std::pair<int const, int>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<int const, int> >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, int> > >::_M_insert_(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::pair<int const, int> const&)':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/bits/stl_tree.h:981: undefined reference to `std::_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalance(int, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Things I have tried**

- Some research pointed towards this being something to do with libc++ vs libstdc++, but I think not, seeing as removing the `insert()` does work. (I also dion't really understand the distinction)
- The above code works fine in a standalone program, compiled with `g++` (no options) or `gcc -lstdc++`.
- I have tried adding `-lstdc++` to the cmake `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, but this didn't seem to make any difference.
- Setting `set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "g++")` in CMakeLists.txt doesn't seem to make any difference.

It must be something to do with the libraries or project setup I suppose, but I would be very grateful for some advice on where to begin looking.

Comment: It is a *template*, so removing a "call" can (and usually will) remove the very *code* underneath that call from your image. Don't take too much stock in the no-call-it-links-fine ideology. I think your approach that a linker mishap in your CMAKE setup is the issue seems sound.

Comment: Thanks. My assumption was that as I can use `std::pair` and `std::map` independently, then the appropriate libraries must be getting linked in correctly. Is that true?

Comment: Run `make VERBOSE=1` and show us the exact commands that are being executed to compile and link the broken piece.  My first guess is that the compiler being used is `gcc` rather than `g++`.

Comment: I concur with John. More 'v's. Verbose output is magic pixie dust of solving build configuration issues.

Comment: I have put the whole output here: http://pastebin.com/Wr0g4yUL, but I'm not sure exactly which lines are important. The file I'm editing is leapfrogjoin.cpp, which compiles (with some others) into libjoin, and then into the final executable minibase-joins. This seems to be dealt with on line 9. thanks for your help. :)

Comment: As you've probably realised I have never used cmake before, so this is part of the reason I'm getting stuck with where to look.

Comment: FYI, line-34 is the one where all the real linkup happens. It is what is responsible for linking your main program object code with all the .a files built in the previous steps. And it looks right provided `/usr/lib64/ccache/c++` properly brings in the appropriate C++ runtime. If it doesn't, then thats the failure point and figuring out how to wedge the right `-l` in there is the ticket. Is this on something like an AIX machine or a Solaris box or something? Just curious.

Comment: No, just a reasonably standard Linux/Xeon box I think.

Comment: Also adding `-lstdc++` to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` does add the `-l` on that line, but doesn't seem to be the one I needed... Would you expect the creation of the map and call to empty to work without this included?